# Bpy check if each object is parented

Tags: python, scripting, parent

I am looking for a way via scripting to check if an object is parented. A way to access the list of its direct children would also be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an object is parented, then its [`parent`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.parent) member will refer to the parent object. Otherwise, `parent` will be empty (`None`).  Here's an example where I've parented a sphere to a monkey.  If I type

```
bpy.data.objects['Sphere'].parent
```

in the Python console window it replies

```
bpy.data.objects['Suzanne']
```

A common test for this is

```
if obj.parent:
    print("Object has a parent".)
```

where `obj` is the object you are interested in.

There is no structure that keeps the list of parents.  Here's a loop that finds all of the children of a specified object, in this case, a monkey:

```
children = []
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj.parent == bpy.data.objects['Suzanne']:
        children.append(obj)
```

This can also be written as

```
children = [obj for obj in bpy.data.objects if obj.parent == bpy.data.objects['Suzanne']]
```

Comment: This answers it, Thank you!

Comment: should bpy.data.objects.parent return a bool?

Comment: No. It returns the parent. The if statement in the example works because Python treats an unset variable as None and then treats None as False.